# Chicken enchiladas still safe to eat

Tags: storage

I cooked chicken and made up enchilada with sour cream and the green sauce and made extra.
How many days can I keep them in the refrigerator before reheating?

Comment: http://www.stilltasty.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would heat within 3 days.  From that point on, first flavor will decay, then quality of tortillas...then, say after about a week, they will get progressively nasty.

Answer (score 0):

I would store for up to three days. If you're concerned about too many leftovers, throw them in the freezer. They will last for 1-2 months and you can have yummy enchiladas any time! I have done this with no negative effects on the taste or structural integrity of the enchilada.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the presence of sour cream, they will keep no longer that any other dairy product. I would be more concerned about the consistency the the tortillas. Have you already stuffed them?

Comment: Downvoted because you are perpetuating the myth that food keeps as short as its most perishable ingredient. This is not true; there are many examples of foods which will keep shorter than their least stable ingredient! In this case, the enchiladas are only good for 3 days, just like any other cooked food, but sour cream will last weeks on its own.